# Unexpected type for keyof mapped type

Tags: typescript, types

I'm using TypeScript 5.3.3 and tried to write a method that returns a key of a given object.

The method works great with `Record`s, but for some reason, it doesn't work as expected for mapped types.
I tried a few things and found that the issue doesn't seem to be caused by my method's typing but TypeScript itself.

```
type Test = keyof { [key: string]: string };
// Test = string | number
```

Where does the `number` come from? And is there a generic way/compiler flag to fix that?
Or is that a TypeScript bug?

```
function objectKey<const T extends Record<string, unknown>>(object: T): keyof T {
  const array: Array<keyof T> = Object.keys(object);
  return this.arrayElement(array);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's a "bug by design". *Sigh*

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug by design to be fair, rather it's Typescript conforming to the oddities of Javascript. Most of the weird bits in Typescript come from the fact that it's a superset of Javascript.

Comment: `number` is a convenient fiction to allow people to write `arr[123]` instead of `arr["123"]`. If JavaScript didn't coerce numeric keys to strings, and actually used numeric keys for array indices, then TS wouldn't have to be weird this way.  Nowadays maybe they'd use `\`${number}\`` instead of `number`, but template literal types didn't exist back when this was implemented, and `\`${number}\`` is also not a perfect match.  TS could have a lot fewer "bug"s if it didn't have to deal with JS being bonkers.